# Modal window using jquery in cake php

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I am new babies to cakephp.I need to create the modal window using jquery in cakephp.
So can anybody sugggest me step by step process for that.I mean how to include the jquery library file needed for modal window in cakephp.

And where to create the jquery function for modal window to open using div in particular view page.

I look at the cakephp site but not much help.

So I really appreciate for any advice.

Thanks
Sabbu

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you are able to write the JavaScript, it should work the same with CakePHP as with 'regular' HTML?

Comment: Hi thaJeztah, thanks for quick reply.Till now i download the jquery ui library file and put those file under webroot.So my all js file are in \cakephp\app\webroot\js\ui folder.When i read cakphp documentation.It mention need to include this files in default.ctp file.So for testing purpose i just put like this echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.9.1'); in head of default.ctp file. I am wonder now  there is lot of js files under ui folder.So how to includes those file in default.ctp file so i can just create simple modal like this $('id').dialog({ height: 140,modal: true}); in one of view page

Comment: Actually my question is simple how to include jquery file needed for to create jquery modal window in cakephp view page.Please help me i hv already spend lot of time on it but unable to get result.

Comment: well, the same as you did with that file, just repeat it, or use an array to specify multiple files (see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::script)). It's also possible to add scripts to the head from within a view, by using the 'inline = false' option.

Comment: I added the jquery reference like this in head of default.ctp file echo $this->Html->script('jquery');echo $this->Html->script('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js'); And also added this line before body tag <?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?><?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();?>.And to simple jquery code to pop up modal window i write this simple code in js_file.js file $(document).ready(function(){ $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({ height: 140,modal: true });});.I also include this file in my view page like this <?php echo $this->Html->script('js_file');?>

Comment: I solve the issue :) thx thaJeztah for your help.